# Making teeth purple in a picture (JES)

Tags: python, jes

What am I doing wrong? I have been trying to create a program for hours to change this man's teeth purple.

```
def makeColor(picture):
    red=getRed(px)
    green=getGreen(px)
    blue=getBlue(px)
    (128 - red, 0 - green, 128 - blue)

    red = makeColor(128)
    green = makeColor(0)
    blue = makeColor(128)
    for x in range (120, 164):
        for y in range(161, 156):
            currentPixel = pic.getPixel(x,y)
            if (distance(red, getColor(currentPixel)) < 165):
                currentPixel.setColor(replacementColor)
```

[Smiling Man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myfy4.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) apply here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 3):

replacementColor has no value.
Also, it appears that your code is looking for red things to turn purple, rather than the white of his teeth.
Perhaps:

```
purple = makeColor(100, 0, 100)  # darken the purple a bit
white = makeColor(128, 128, 128)
...
        if (distance(white, getColor(currentPixel)) < 165):
            currentPixel.setColor(purple)
```

Comment: Can you give me more input? I may not being the code right at all. I need to create a program to make the teeth in the photo attached, purple.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell he means that you have not given any value to color purple. Give it some value and look for white color instead of red. He has given you code and explained what you are doing wrong. Don't know what sort of more input might some need after that

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/5566302/alexander-campbell: Repeating the high-level problem does not tell me where you are stuck.  You wrote a program that does not run at all.  I left you a comment above that links to pages to help you write a clear question.  The code you provided does not run, due to the undefined variables.  If it did run, it would not do what you want.  Until you better explain what you're doing, I don't know how to help you.  "Give me more input" is not a problem description.